# Meaning of an expression

Tags: meaning, expressions

What exactly does this expression mean ?

"its not you or her."

I heard this sentence from a native English speaker and I don't want to explain more! I hope this sentence itself would be sufficient for you to help me! :)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your question to provide additional context— preceding and following sentences, what the conversation was regarding, and so on; otherwise, it is impossible to say what is meant. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean

> It's not you and it's not her.

or possibly

> It's not a choice between you and her.

Comment: Then apparently he is lying ! ;) anyway, thank you very much!